# Java servlet tracing API hit rate

Tags: java, servlets

I'm trying to build a HTTP API using the very basic j2ee servlet, with MySQL.

There's a requirement where I have to limit how frequent a particular user calls our server. Say when I detect their TPS limit is 20, once they made 21st call on the same second, I need to return error.

So far there's 2 methods that I know how can I achieve this:

## 1. Database datetime field

```
=========================
UserId | Datetime | Count
=========================
-- On every calls made (there's unique index on userId + datetime)
INSERT INTO hitrate (userId, datetime, count) VALUES (123, NOW(), 1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count = count + 1;

-- Before every call, check
SELECT count FROM hitrate where userId = 123 and datetime = NOW();
```

All I need to do is to return an error once I see the count is above 20. Disadvantage is that it involves too much database transactions, and latency between each is killing, so this method is big no.

## 2. HashMap

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> hitrate = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

String tag = inUsername + "-" + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

Integer count = hitrate.get(tag);
if (count == null) {
    hitrate.put(tag, 1);
} else {
    if (count >= 20) {
        // return error;
    } else {
        count++;
        hitrate.put(tag, count);
    }
}
```

This is more efficient when it comes to resources and time required. But the thing is my hashmap is going to get larger and larger.

Does anyone has experience in managing this and know what is the best approach to come out with this logic?

Thank you.

Comment: You can either try to implement a [leaky-bucket algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_bucket) or use a poor-mans solution (as we do) and just have a (distributed) cache as holder for the request numbers per user and clear that cache every n time units and block if the cache contains a higher number of requests for a user than a certain threshold. While this might allow 2 times the number of requests within an oberservation timeframe in worst case, the overhead of managing the lockout is very simple and therefore quick to implement. I wouldn't use or recommend a DB therefore

Comment: Note that your 2nd approach will lead to an OOM error sooner or later as you always add to the cache but never remove from it. Also, I'm not sure if creating a tag for a username + millisecond combination is actually what you want if you want to limit incoming requests for the same second. Either convert the millis to seconds for your tag or just store the username and clear the cache every n seconds for simplicity reasons

Comment: @RomanVottner Yes thanks for pointing out the mistake there, it's supposed to be traced in seconds. Based on your suggestion, best method I can think of is to re-declare the hashmap about every five minutes. But let's see if anyone could come out with a better suggestions. =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking for something called "Rate limiter".
This can be done in numerous ways.
For example, there is a Rate Limiter in a well-known [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) library

Implementing it over RDBMS is not a good approach IMO, because the database calls are quite expensive, although it can be a viable solution for small setups.

However, compared to the hashmap solution that you've offered and the Guava approach, it will work if you have more a cluster of servers in your setup and want to limit the user access regardless the server called by the user.

If you have this kind of setup, you'll have to go to "distributed" solution.

One such a solution is over [Redis](https://redis.io/).

There is even a library for this: [ratelimitj](https://github.com/mokies/ratelimitj).

Comment: Hi Mark. I'm a volunteer editor at Stack Overflow, and alongside a number of other editors, I try to help keep posts readable for the benefit of future readers. We tend to fix punctuation, grammar, spacing, formatting and trim chatty material. Your posts tend to always need fixing, in particular the amount of conversational material, which is generally thought not to be appropriate for a Q&A site. When writing questions or answers here, we're a bit more like Wikipedia than a chatroom or a forum. There's plenty of references I can get for you from Meta, if they are of interest.

Comment: In particular, "hope this helps", while well-meaning, is redundant. We could add it to the answer template, so that all 24 million answers get the same boilerplate, but given that this state of affairs can be assumed, it would keep things succinct not to do so. After all, no-one posts hoping that their material does _not_ help!

Comment: When your answers are edited, you will get a little notification icon to say that someone has taken the time to improve your work even more. If you could click on these to examine what sort of changes people are making, it would save us a great deal of effort - it will mean that we're not working against people who are adding more chatty material at the same time as our trying to reduce it. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Why didn't you send me a direct message or something? Anyway, I apologize if it doesn't fit the format. Since English my forth language actually, I really try to do my best to answer as good as I can, but I'm affraid I won't be able to guarantee that my posts will be syntax / punctuation mistakes free ( I already use gramarly service). As for the "personal attitude" in my posts, noted. If it's really violates the format of the site, I'll try to improve my posts, so no "hope this helps" anymore :)

Comment: Person-to-person direct messages are not supported here - there is private chat, but only mods can open that. Thanks for the response `:-)`. Don't worry about minor errors - editors can fix those.

Comment: Noted. Thanks and sorry again for inconvenience